# Why the Activity does not change the state of view when buttons are clicked?

Tags: android, eclipse, onclick, android-activity

I have 18 ScrollViews in a LinearLayout, that change their state of visibility when some integers are added up when buttons are clicked. 
The problem is that the if statement from my code works only when I have just 4-5 ScrollViews.
But when I have all my layouts in place, it does nothing.
What have I done wrong?

activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/question_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/question_1"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b1_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/next_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/a1_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/choix_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/a1_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:background="@drawable/choix_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/question_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/question_2"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b2_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/next_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/a2_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/choix_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/a2_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:background="@drawable/choix_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/question_3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/question_3"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b3_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/next_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/a3_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/choix_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/a3_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:background="@drawable/choix_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/question_4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/question_4"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/result_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b4_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/next_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b4_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/a4_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/choix_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/a4_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:background="@drawable/choix_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back_btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b4_btn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/avant_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>



    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/eerner_scroll"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/eerner_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/eerner"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/eerner"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/frameinfo"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/infoscreen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/infoscreen"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/info"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/eerney_scroll"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/eerney"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/eerney"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/eerney"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/einteg_scroll"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/einteg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/einteg"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/einteg"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/einter_scroll"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/einter"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/einter"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/einter"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ekommr_scroll"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ekommr"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ekommr"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ekommr"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ekommy_scroll"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ekommy"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ekommy"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ekommy"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ekompb_scroll"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ekompb"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ekompb"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ekompb"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ekompg_scroll"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ekompg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ekompg"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ekompg"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ekoorb_scroll"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ekoorb"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ekoorb"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ekoorb"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ekoory_scroll"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ekoory"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ekoory"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ekoory"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/epragb_scroll"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/epragb"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/epragb"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/epragb"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </ScrollView>

     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/epragy_scroll"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/epragy"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/epragy"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/epragy"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </ScrollView>

     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/eprufb_scroll"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/eprufb"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/eprufb"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/eprufb"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </ScrollView>

     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/eprufg_scroll"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/eprufg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/eprufg"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/eprufg"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </ScrollView>

     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/estabg_scroll"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/estabg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/estabg"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/estabg"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </ScrollView>

     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/estabr_scroll"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/estabr"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/estabr"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/estabr"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </ScrollView>



    </LinearLayout>
```

ActivityMain.java

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ScrollView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int a1_val = 0;
    int b1_val = 0;
    int a2_val = 0;
    int b2_val = 0;
    int a3_val = 0;
    int b3_val = 0;
    int a4_val = 0;
    int b4_val = 0;
    int eerner = 4844;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Buttons for start screen
        ImageButton clicks =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.clicks);
        ImageButton new_test_btn =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.new_test_btn);
    ImageButton view_profile_btn =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.view_profile_btn);
        ImageButton home_btn =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_btn);
        ImageButton info_btn =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.info_btn);

        //Buttons for question_1
        Button a1_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.a1_btn);
        Button b1_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1_btn);
        Button next_btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.next_btn1);

        //Buttons for question_2
        Button a2_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.a2_btn);
        Button b2_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2_btn);
        Button next_btn2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.next_btn2);
        Button back_btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.back_btn1);

        //Buttons for question_3
        Button a3_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.a3_btn);
        Button b3_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b3_btn);
        Button next_btn3 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.next_btn3);
        Button back_btn2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.back_btn2);

        //Buttons for question_4
        Button a4_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.a4_btn);
        Button b4_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b4_btn);
        Button result_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.result_btn);
        Button back_btn3 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.back_btn3);



        // a1 click
        a1_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {a1_val = 1;};});

        // b1 click
        b1_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {b1_val = 5;};});

        //a2 click
        a2_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {a2_val = 22;};});

        //b2 click
        b2_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {b2_val = 66;};});

        //a3 click
        a3_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {a3_val = 333;};});

        //b3 click
        b3_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {b3_val = 777;};});

        //a4 click
        a4_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {a4_val = 4444;};});

        //b4 click
        b4_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {b4_val = 8888;};});

        //result click
        result_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if  (a1_val + b2_val + a3_val + a4_val == eerner);
            ScrollView eerner_scroll = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.eerner_scroll);
            eerner_scroll.setVisibility(ScrollView.VISIBLE);

        };});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're asking, but assuming it's the if that's causing you trouble:

```
if  (a1_val + b2_val + a3_val + a4_val == eerner);
```

... you should get rid of the `;` and put the conditional code in a `{}` block. As it is now, if the condition evaluates to true, an empty statement block is executed and then the code proceeds with `ScrollView eerner_scroll = ...` regardless of what was in the conditional `if`.